# Prove that $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{(1-a_n)} \geq 1 - \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{a_n}$

Tags: inequality, summation, products

The following proof is obtained from this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02701v3.pdf).

[image]

My question is how to obtain the inequality.

My guess is because of the following inequality:

$$\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{(1-a_n)} \geq 1 - \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{a_n}$$

By the condition given in the statement, we know that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{a_n}$ converges. Thus, the product $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{(1-a_n)}$ converges. But I don't know how to prove the inequality.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: i think it's a condition on $\eta$ to calculate the value of $\eta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Induction on $n$. If $0\leq a_j\leq 1$ for $j\in N$ then we have $\prod_{j=1}^n(1-a_j)\geq 1-\sum_{j=1}^na_j$ for every $n\in N.$ PROOF. The case $n=1$ is trivial.If case $n$ is true, then $$\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}(1-a_j)=[\;\prod_{j=1}^n(1-a_j)\;]\cdot(1-a_{n+1})\geq$$    $$\geq [1-\sum_{j=1}^na_j\;]\cdot(1-a_{n+1})=[1-\sum_{j=1}^na_j]-a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^na_j\geq$$ $$\geq [1-\sum_{j=1}^na_j]-a_{n+1}=1-\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}a_j$$ so case $n+1$ is true.

Comment: Corollary .If $1>a_n\geq 0$ then $\prod_{n\in N}(1-a_n) \ne 0 \iff  \sum_{n\in N} a_n<\infty $

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k) \ge 1- \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, and $a_{n+1} \in (0,1)$, then
$(1-a_{n+1}) \prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k) \ge (1-a_{n+1})(1- \sum_{k=1}^n a_k) = 1-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k + a_{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \ge 1- \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a_k$.

Answer (score 4):

First, note the following.
$$
\Pi_{n\in \mathbb{N}} (1-a_n) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\Pi_{i=0}^{k} (1-a_n)
$$
and similarly
$$
1-\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n = 1-\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_n.
$$
Let
$$
b_k = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\Pi_{i=0}^{k} (1-a_n)
$$
and
$$
c_k = 1-\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_n.
$$
The claim that you are asking follows if we can show that $b_k\geq c_k$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$. This can be proven by induction. We would need to look at a sequence of statements of the following sort. 
$$
P(k) : b_k\geq c_k \text{ for all }k.
$$
Let's take $P(0)$ as the base case. This is easy to see because $b_0 = c_0 = 1-a_0$, confirming $P(0)$.

Next, we will try to prove that $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$. Note that $b_{k+1} = b_k \times (1-a_{k+1})$ and $c_{k+1} = c_k-a_{k+1}$. Consider the following.
$$
c_{k+1} = c_k-a_{k+1}  = c_k - a_{k+1}\frac{c_k}{c_k} = c_k\left( 1 - \frac{a_{k+1}}{c_k} \right)
$$
For simplicity let's assume that $c_k>0$, because otherwise the sequence of $c_k$ would be less than 0, which automatically satisfies the original claim. Nowe notice that $c_k<1$, hence 
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{a_{k+1}}{c_k} \right)<1-a_{k+1}.
$$
As a result, since $b_k>c_k$ by assumption, we have
$$
b_{k+1}= b_k \times (1-a_{k+1}) > c_k \times\left( 1 - \frac{a_{k+1}}{c_k}\right)= c_{k+1}
$$
which proves the conjecture.